# Flutter Learning Roadmap

Tags: flutter

I just a little bit of struggle when learning flutter and understand it in short period , can you share your experience with me , how to understand and learn flutter rapidly and properly ? 
Very welcome anything of your comment! :D

Comment: Hi Andre. Glad to hear you are interested in Flutter but for getting started I suggest you check out some of the other community places at https://flutter.dev/community. Stack Overflow isn't really a good fit for this, as it focuses on answering specific questions and issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nice you are interested in a flutter technology, so I was the complete beginner and I have learned a lot from the flutter.dev/community, they have the well-documented architecture.

Second, one is the youtube is where you can learn more and better if you do not like the documentation.

I have learned a lot from these two youtube playlist listed below:

1): https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlxmoA0rQ-Lw6tAs2fGFuXGP13-dWdKsB

2) :https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR2qQy0Zxs_UdqAcaipPR3CG1Ly57UlhV

Comment: I myself only started learning flutter less than 2 months ago, and I'm getting ready to release my first app on the app store by the end of the week.  Most of my help was from youtube, (quick searches for specific small snippets I'm working with) but places like https://pub.dev/ (for specific packages) can really help depending on what you're trying to achieve.  Best of luck!

Comment: Hi there , i'm very glad to know some references from your , i wish it can help me alot to learn this new technology for me , Good luck too for you guys